# Confused about Linux "route add" commands for this diagram

Tags: routing, router, linux

I am confused about this [network diagram](https://www.cs.umb.edu/~gghinita/it443/network-diagram.pdf).

In class the router R1 was assigned to me and other students were given various routers/workstations on the diagram. Our task was to set the network up with ifconfig and route commands. Since the main router only really had one physical interface, we used an alias as well (eth0 and eth0:1).

I used the following commands to set up R1 (initially I had the gateways wrong) but my professor corrected me:

```
# set interfaces (1 physical/1 virtual)
  ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.4/24
  ifconfig eth0:1 10.0.14.252/24

# Add routes for remaining 4 LANs:
  route add -net 10.0.12.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.14.27
  route add -net 10.0.17.0 netmask 255.255.255.0  gw 10.0.14.34
  route add -net 10.0.7.0 netmask 255.255.255.0  gw 10.0.14.27
  route add -net 10.0.28.0 netmask 255.255.255.0  gw 10.0.14.34

# once everyone can ping eachother successfully
# connect the entire 10.0.0.0/24 network to the
# outside 192.168.104.0/22 network
  route add default gw 10.0.0.1

# set up forwarding to outside gateway
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

I am most confused about why the gw's for the route commands are 10.0.14.34 and 10.0.14.27.

What would the route commands and gateways be for R3 or R5? Or R2 and R4? I can see that a router's two adjacent networks get added with the two ifconfig commands; there is no need to set their routes. But I am really getting confused on what each side of each router is using for a gateway.

Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You need the static routes to know how to reach networks that aren't directly connected to your router. The gw for the routes is set for the IP of next hop in the connected network in the path to the remote network. Every device in the path  would need a static route for the remote network until you reach the device where the gw for the remote network is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A gateway is like a door leading to other subnets. In order to reach a subnet in question you need to know which door to use.

On R3 you'd need:

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.14.252
route add -net 10.0.12.0 netmask 255.255.255.0  gw 10.0.14.27
route add -net 10.0.7.0 netmask 255.255.255.0  gw 10.0.14.27
route add -net 10.0.28.0 netmask 255.255.255.0  gw 10.0.17.28
```

On R5 you can use R3 as the default gateway as all non-local subnets are behind it:

```
route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 10.0.17.24
```

Comment: Thank you Zac67. That answer is exactly what I was looking for. My apologies that this was marked off topic.

Comment: makes so much more sense now!